# Evaluating permissions in a legacy Android app

Tags: android, permissions

I have an older Android app which we are trying to remove some permissions from the manifest which we believe to be no longer required.

Is there a method in which we can determine any calls used by our application which do require permissions to be explicitly stated?  Such as compiler flags, or static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways to know that, erase them all and in the LogCat will be displayed permissions needed. (Not the best option, but still an option)

Asking for permissions programmatically. More references [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Something like this:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```